# theme and wall paper for 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, themes, desktop-background

I upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 recently and realized that 13.10 provides more choice for themes and wall paper.

Is it true that 14.04 LTS has less theme and wall paper?
If yes, are there any way that I can down load themes and wall paper for version 13.10.
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Iccsi

Comment: I don't know comparison between 13.10 and 14.04 themes for unity but I know Cinnamon desktop environment has whole lot of themes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install themes on your Ubuntu 14.04, [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html) is a great collection of it. 
Select the theme, and follow the instruction to install it. 
Once installed, you can select it from the **Appearance** menu in **System Settings**.

For wallpapers, simply right clicking on an image and selecting "set as wallpaper" would be sufficient. However you can also add you wallpaper images in `/usr/share/backgrounds/` directory to appear in the **Appearance** setting.

Comment: An alternate but not so convenient way: You can also visit gnome-look.org, download requisite/liked themes, and copy the directory to either /usr/share/themes or $HOME/.themes. You will need sudo access for writing to /usr/share/themes. Plus side of this method is that not all themes in the noobslab ppa are immediately updated, and not all nice themes are included in the ppa. Downside is you have to do stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more themes from omgubuntu.com. you can download the gnome environment and change the working environment which looks more like a theme. Just extract the targ file and restart your computer and change the working environment by clicking on the uduntu sign on the login screen you should have options there to choose the environment you want. Hope this information was useful